# $\mathbb{R}^{[a,b]}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

what is the meaning of this in linear difference equations context.
$\mathbb{R}^{[a,b]}$
when $a, b\in \mathbb{R} $.

I can understand $\mathbb{R}^2$ but $\mathbb{R}$ to power interval?
I need intuition.

Answer (score 5):

This is a notation for maps from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: so $\mathbb{R}^{[a,b]}$ is not forming any  vector space?

Comment: It is a vector space, you can define a punctual addition and multiplication on this set of maps. Check that theses operations satisfy the vector spaces axioms.

Comment: so what is the meaning of $p \in \mathbb{R}^{[a,b]}$. Does it mean p is a function (or map) of x or ? like $ p (x) : [a,b] \rightarrow   \mathbb{R}$

Comment: $p\in\mathbb{R}^{[a,b]}$ means that $p$ is a map from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, namely $p$ takes $x\in[a,b]$ and $p(x)\in\mathbb{R}$.